Issue with MD02 Temperature and Sensor (MODBUS)
Have an issue with the MD-02 sensor
The sensor was working fine till I "tried" to change the slave address from 0x01 to 0x02 using the command as per the above datasheet.
The command executed successfully, however, after that the device is not responding either on the old or the new address.
Tried using MODBUS scanner - getting error responses only on the 0x0 address, timeouts on all other slave addresses
Is there any way to debug or recover from this condition.
